# service android don't start when boot in specific phones

Tags: android, service, boot

I have created a service, it start fine in samsung devices but in alcatel phones is not start when the phone is booting, my code of manifest is below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.app.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="Version">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application android:name="com.redcentral.redcentral.AnalyticsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name="com.app.app.ScheduleReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.app.app.NotificationService" android:enabled="true"></service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.app.app.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.app.app.MainActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

What is wrong or what is i need to add to start when phone is starting?

This is my ScheduleReceiver code

```
public class ScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    /***** For start Service  ****/
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `ScheduleReciver` please?

Comment: I've post my ScheduleReciver post now...

Comment: Piris, solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, AFAIK there are some devices that have a `Statup Manager menu` in their settings, so make sure that your `Alcatel` has that option checked, also check if your `Settings` > `Power` > `Fast Boot` is enable or disable, it should be enable.